# Why do we need to use 3 quotes while executing sql query from python cursor?

Tags: python, mysql

I came across some Python programs that connect to a MySQL database. In the code, I saw the query in the `execute()` function is enclosed withing 3 quotations(`"""`). I would like to know the reason for this.  I also noticed that 3 quotes are used only while creating, inserting, and updating the table and not while selecting a row.

```
cursor.execute("""create table student(id char(10),name char(10))""")
cursor.execute("select * from student")
```

Why?

Answer (score 23):

It is not needed--the coder who made that just decided to use it for some reason (probably to add emphasis on that part).

A triple-quoted string is just that: a string.  It has the same properties as a regular string object.  There are only two differences:

1. It supports multiple lines.  This saves you from having to place `\n` every time you want a newline.
2. It allows you to have single and double quotes without escaping.  This could be useful with SQL commands.

In summary though, a triple-quoted string is a string:

```
>>> type("""a""")
<type 'str'>
>>> type("a")
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

and it is not *needed* in that code.

Comment: Not the *only* difference: also, if allows both single and double quotes without escaping, which might be useful in an SQL command.

Comment: Wow, nice catch.  Let me add that.