# Inserting Python Variable in SQL satement

Tags: python, mysql

I've been trying to make the following code work but have not found a way. Im new to Python and know a little of MySQL. Connecting Python with MySQL is something I recently learned for my college project.

```
import mysql.connector

password = input("Enter Password Here")
print(password)

conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="root", database="trial")
c2 = conn2.cursor()
c2.execute("select lastname from table1 where lastname= '?' ", (password))
row1 = c2.fetchone()

print(row1)

if(c2==password):
   print("Welcome User")
else:
   print("Invalid")
```

My connection with the database is working just fine and the SQL statements are also executing as expected. The only problem is that when inserting the `password` variable. The `print(row1)` code outputs `None` in the Console. Please Help

Comment: Why would lastname be the same as password?

Comment: The name of the password column in the database was named as lastname. It's Just in the back end.

Comment: You are saving passwords as plaintext. This is a really bad idea. Is this an old project that you need to maintain now or is it a new project?

Comment: We will be asking for password input in the GUI as bullets. This is just for Debugging purposes

Comment: Asterisks in a GUI do not matter. Saving passwords as cleartext is the worst you can do to your customers.

Comment: Yes, but this is just a college project :) .  I am fairly new to Python and SQL, please excuse me

Comment: Still, there is no excuse. Doing it like this is the wrong answer. Learn how to do it properly!

Comment: @0Dz Have you tried the same query in mysql?

Comment: I have tried it. It works but inserting python variable is a pain

Comment: @NilsWerner Yes, I will. Thank You for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
c2.execute("""select lastname from table1 where lastname= %s""", (password,))
```

Comment: I got these errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GammeCore/PycharmProjects/untitled/SQL Debug.py", line 8, in <module>
    c2.execute("select lastname from table1 where lastname= ?", (password))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: I'm sorry but i still got the same errors. I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @0Dz What if you try `q = ("select lastname from table1 where lastname= %s")` and then run `c2.execute(q, (password))`?

Comment: I still got the same errors. The SQL statement is working perfectly in MySQL

Comment: @0Dz : FOLLOW the instruction.  For MySQL or PostgreSQL, use`%s` . Only SQLite use `?`

Comment: @mootmoot I have tried the code with both %s and ? .  I still keep getting errors with both of them.

Comment: @0Dz Try `c2.execute("""select lastname from table1 where lastname= %s""", (password,))`

Comment: @Nurzhan It Worked!! But, could you please explain what went wrong and how you fixed it?? Why did you place the comma after password and what is the need of 3 pairs of inverted commas?

Comment: @0Dz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479853/why-do-we-need-to-use-3-quotes-while-executing-sql-query-from-python-cursor

Comment: @0Dz Well, this is how queried are made in python to mysql db. The important thing is the parameters - it accepts tuple, this is why you need to write `(password,)` to make it a tuple, otherwise it is considered as a string.

Comment: @mootmoot Thank You

Comment: @Nurzhan Ok got it. If I want to place multiple variables for input and/ or output, do i have to place the commas after the variable all the time?

Comment: @0Dz No, if there is more than 1 parameter than you don't need to put comma in the end. For instance `(password, login)` will work.

Comment: @Nurzhan Thank You for your time!!