# Output of print("""Hello World's"s""""") in python 3.6

Tags: python

I read that anything between triple quotes inside print is treated literal so tried messing things a little bit. Now I am not able to get above statement working. I searched internet but could not find anything.

statement:

```
print("""Hello World's"s""""")
```

Output I am getting:

```
Hello World's"s
```

Expected output:

```
Hello World's"s""
```

Comment: A string which starts with `"""` ends at the first occurrence of `"""` after that, so the whole string with quotes is `"""Hello World's"s"""` and it is followed by an empty string withing single quotes `""`. It is valid to put two string one after the other and it is same as concatenating it. So, your input is equivalent to `"""Hello World's"s"""  ""`

Answer (score 3):

`print("""Hello World's"s""""")` is seen as `print("""Hello World's"s""" "")` because when python find `"""` it automatically ends the previous string beginning with a triple double-quote.

Try this:

```
>>> print("a"'b')
ab
```

So basically your '"""Hello World's"s"""""' is just `<str1>Hello World's"s</str1><str2></str2>` with str2 an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Triple quoted string is usually used for doc-string.
As @zimdero pointed out [Triple-double quote v.s. Double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643894/triple-double-quote-v-s-double-quote)
You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/19479874/1768843
And https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

If you really want to get the result you want just use `\"` or just you can do combination with ``` `` ```, `.format()` etc

```
print("Hello World's\"s\"\"")
```

https://repl.it/repls/ThatQuarrelsomeSupercollider

Comment: The `""` and `""" """` string should be same. Sure there are some benefits for using `""" """` but it's not necessary. Anyway thanks for reminding that.

Comment: Triple quotes are useful anywhere you want a newline to be part of the text. They are also useful if you want`"` and `'` to be part of the text. But as OP found out, you still need to escape triple quotes inside triple quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Triple quotes within a triple-quoted string must still be escaped for the same reason a single quote within a single quoted string must be escaped: The string parsing ends as soon as python sees it. As mentioned, once tokenized your string is equivalent to

```
"""Hello World's"s""" ""
```

That is, two strings which are then concatenated by the compiler. Triple quoted strings can include newlines. Your example is similar to

```
duke = """Thou seest we are not all alone unhappy:
This wide and universal theatre
Presents more woeful pageants than the scene
Wherein we play in."""

jaques = """All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players:
They have their exits and their entrances;
And one man in his time plays many parts."""
```

If python was looking for the outermost triple quotes it would only have defined one string here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with `'''` to not complicate things:

```
print('''Hello World's"s""''')
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
print("\"\"Hello World's's\"\"")
```

Output:

```
""Hello World's's""
```

Comment: No, the OP is wanting to do this with triple quotes.